# How can I have the battery life permanently displayed in the top bar?

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery

I already installed Tweaks, so now I know the percentage of my battery life. But what I really want to know consequently is: how long will it last?

Comment: This depends on the desktop you use ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can install this gnome-shell extension to achieve this : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/817/battery-status/

Once installed, go to your gnome extension settings page (https://extensions.gnome.org/local/), and click on the settings icon of the newly installed "*Battery Status*" extension. You will have many options to customize the display, including showing the remaining time instead of the percentage.

Hope it helps !

Comment: it did, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped ! Please mark this answer as the selected answer to that other people can easily get helped too :-)